# Syntax error on token "11", invalid VariableDeclaratorId R.java

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/11" />

</LinearLayout>
```

All it is, is the android project normal setup and I put this in and the image 11 in each of the folders the same size as the default icon, I cant get it to go into the emulator because of this error, it wont even run, can you help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rename your drawable with a name that contains letters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/my_drw" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It need only start with a letter (or perhaps `_`?), the rest can be numbers. It basically has the same logic as variable names with the added restriction of only lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. In my project **res** folder there was no **drawable** folder. I made a new folder named ***"drawable"*** and added my image ***xyz.jpg*** to it. But i got same error in **R.java file.** Then i copied **ic_launcher.png** file from **drawable-hdpi** folder to ***drawable*** and it worked. Somehow i sensed that folder should have **ic_launcher.png** image.